# Python regex *_*_policy pattern to match *_*_policies

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = "abc_xyz_policy"
search_string = """
bla bla
abc_xyz_policies
bla bla
"""
```

I can make

```
pattern = pattern[:-1] + "ies"
```

and

```
search = re.search(pattern, search_string)
```

to make it work.

However, I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this pattern `abc_xyz_polic(?:y|ies)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

- a non-capturing group at the end to match either `y` or `ies`
- use wor boundary or word boundaries to make sure you match the whole word.

You need

```py
search = re.search(r'\babc_xyz_polic(?:ies|y)\b', search_string)
```

where

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `abc_xyz_polic` - a literal text
- `(?:ies|y)` - `ies` or `y`
- `\b` - a word boundary.